# Ease of pulling in a pulley question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

> Consider the two arrangements shown in fig. (i and ii)
>
> [image]
>
> Statement 1: It is easier to pull the block in case (ii) than in case (i)
>
> Statement 2: In case (ii), a larger fraction of the weight of the block is shared by the ceiling.

The answer is given that both statement are true and statement 2 is the reason for statement 1.

Though I somewhat agree with statement 2 but how can we say it easier to pull if to pull the block same distance in each case work done by Force must be equal.

Comment: "same distance" is key to your question: if you pull the rope down $d$, how far does the mass rise in each case?

Comment: I meant to say if we pull 'the block' by same distance as the question asks the ease to pull block rather than the rope.

Comment: Hello! I have tried my best to convert the text of the image to actual written text though I wasn't sure at some points. Please correct if I did any mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: "Easier" often means spreading the effort over a longer time or distance: imagine going up a hill on a bicycle - it is often easier if you use a lower gear or spiral round the hill

Comment: Re, "Statement 2..." Here's a hint: How much of the "weight of the block" is supported by the person who is pulling _down_ on the end of the rope?

Answer (score 0):

Easier in this context would mean less force, not less work.  So you could translate

> It is easier to pull the block in case (ii) than in case (i)

to

> The minimum force required to lift the block is lower in case (ii) than in case (i)

or

> When holding the block stationary, the required force in case (ii) is lower than in case (i)

Answer (score 0):

For the work done to be equal, when the mass is lifted the same height, same amount of force must act **on the mass** (here I am not referring to the force you exert to pull the rope). So let's take that force as $F$. In the first figure that force $F$ is shared by one pulley (as one pulley is connected to the mass), so you have to pull the rope with$\frac F2$ force. But in the second figure, two pulleys are attached to the mass, so $\frac F4$ on the rope is enough to pull the mass. Though in both cases, same $F$ net force is acting on the mass. So when you pull the block same distance, the work done is equal.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in the second case you will need to pull a longer stretch of rope in order to lift the block up a certain distance.

Thus, while you are able to apply a smaller force to lift the block, this force will need to be applied such that the displacement of the point at which you grab de rope will be greater if you want to move the block a given distance.

This increase in distance is of the same proportion as the obtained decrease in force (each pulley halves the required force and doubles the required pulling distance). Therefore the final work needed under the assumption of 0 dissipation will be the same.